# How can I set an element inside my directive to disabled?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple directive with a template that's 6-7 lines long. Here's an example that is similar to my directive but I have just used a simple one line template and an `<input>` here to cut down on the number of lines in the question.

```
app.directive('abc', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '^ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input name="lname" disabled>',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope: any, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {           
        }
    };
});
```

This particular one is just an example but I hope someone can use it to give me some advice.

What I need to do is to be able to set the disabled of this input in html something like this:

```
 <abc disabled="{{isDisabled}}">
```

Can someone give me some advice how I can do this. Note that in this example I hardcoded the word disabled but I would like this to be set at run time in my application.

Thank you

Comment: So, you want to reinvent the ngDisabled directive that angular provides. Why?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't so clear.  My real code has a 6-7 line template but just to keep it simple I cut it down to the one line and used input as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), so your template can use, for example, a scope variable called `ngDisabled`:

```
template: '<input name="lname" ng-disabled="ngDisabled">',
```

The reason why I've chosen the scope variable to be `ngDisabled`, is so you can use the following in the directive definition

```
scope: {
  ngModel: '=',
  ngDisabled: '='
},
```

Then using the `<abc>` element can the attribute `ng-disabled`

```
 <abc ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-model="myModel">
```

Note I'm using, `ng-disabled` rather than `disabled` to make it clear it's used like the usual `ng-disabled` attribute, and to never conflict with the HTML attribute `disabled`.

Comment: Michael - Thanks for your reply but i would like to be able to set the disable at the level of the <abc>  Can you maybe add to your question to give an example including the HTML

Comment: @Alan I slightly misunderstood. I've edited my question.